# Module installed and enabled but doesn't show up

Tags: magento2, module, extensions

I installed a module and the files are correct and the commands worked just fine but when I go to System > Advanced, it doesn't show up in the disable modules section at all but it shows up when I run module:status and it says enabled.

This is what I tried so far after installing the module:

- Ran module:status and it shows as enabled
- Ran setup:db-schema:upgrade
- Ran setup:db-data:upgrade
- Flushed all cache
- Checked /app/etc/config.php and it shows up there
- Switched to developer mode and back to production mode
- Installed module in developer and production mode but no change
- Installed old version of the same module that worked before and no change
- Deleted entries from setup_module table and then redid install

Database related maybe?

**UPDATE:** After many attempts, I was finally able to see the module enabled in the System > Advanced > Modules section but I'm still not able to see the module section under the Store > Configuration so how can I get the module to install the necessary code to make that happen?

Comment: Is there registration.php file ?

Comment: @KishanPatadia Yes there is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing module

delete your generation and cache folder inside var

Run setup:upgrade

Run static-content:deploy

Comment: read my details because I already did all of that

Comment: you can check in log files. if there is any error showing there. Also try to delete pub/static (require,frontend,adminhtml) and than repeat the steps.

Comment: tried that and it didn't work